# PHP hash key not found: what is the expected behavior?

Tags: php, hashtable, lookup

I've heard that you get an error if you try to access a key in a hash that doesn't exist.

However, I seem to just get an empty string, or a null value.

Example:

```
<?php

$hash = array("abc" => 123,
              "def" => 456
);

echo "a key that's in the hash: <" . $hash["abc"] . "><br />";

echo "a key that's not in the hash: <" . $hash["ghi"] . ">";

?>
```

The output is:

```
a key that's in the hash: <123>
a key that's not in the hash: <>
```

**What's going on here?**

I'm using PHP v5.3.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably hiding your notice errors (more info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)). 
Put this at the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Comment: What does that mean -- `hiding your notices`?  I don't think I have control over the configuration files.

Comment: @MattFenwick - Notices are lower level warnings that came be omitted without disrupting execution.  You don't actually need to change the conf files, you can use `ini_set` programmatically in execution as Wesley described to see the messages.

Comment: @DeaconDesperado -- thanks guys, I'm getting a warning now.  I suppose there's probably also a way to override the default configuration to make it throw non-ignorable errors?

Comment: @MattFenwick Yep, you just set `error_reporting=E_ALL` and `display_errors=on` in PHP.ini... But that's (effectively) what you have done by using the above solution. It's probably best to do it at runtime if you are on a box that has any production use, but if it is a pure dev server, you can enable it in PHP.ini.

Answer (score 1):

As Wesley van Opdorp said, your current error reporting settings could hide notice errors.

You can enable all errors with this code snippet (at the top of your script):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Anyway I would recommend you to check if a certain key exists via `isset()`:

```
if ( isset($array['key']) )
{
  /* exists */
}
else
{
  /* doesn't exist */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on **error_reporting** setting.
You will get **Undefined offset** notice if you set `error_reporting = E_ALL`

```
>php -d error_reporting='E_ALL' -r '$a=array(); print $a["b"];'
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant b - assumed 'b' in Command line code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() Command line code:0
....
```